# Install multiple private packages from Github using Poetry and deploy keys

Tags: python, github, ssh, python-poetry, deploy-keys

I want to install multiple private Github repositories as python packages into my repository using poetry. This works fine when running `poetry install` locally as I have my public SSH key added to Github which allows poetry to access the private repos. The problem is that I want to install these same private packages in my CI/CD pipeline and for that I need to add one deploy key per repo. The correct deploy key needs to be used towards the correct repository and for that to work, I need to setup a config with some aliases on the following format (I haven't actually gotten so far as to know whether this will actually work or not):

```
// /.ssh/config
Host repo-1.github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo-1-deploy-key
Host repo-2.github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo-2-deploy-key
```

Where `repo-1` and `repo-2` are the names of the private repositories I need to install. When running locally the `pyproject.toml` packages need to be setup in the following format:

```
// pyproject.toml
...
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
repo-1 = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/equinor/repo-1.git" }
repo-2 = { git = "ssh://git@github.com/equinor/repo-2.git" }
...
```

As this will allow the developer to install the packages without any configuration (given that they have access). For the CI/CD pipeline however, the URLs need to match the alias in the SSH config file and therefore it needs to look something like this:

```
// pyproject.toml
...
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
repo-1 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-1.github.com/equinor/repo-1.git" }
repo-2 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-2.github.com/equinor/repo-2.git" }
...
```

Now, where I seem to be stuck at is on **how I can include two different git paths in the same pyproject file?** I tried the following:

```
//pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
repo-1 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-1.github.com/equinor/repo-1.git", optional=true }
repo-2 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-2.github.com/equinor/repo-2.git", optional=true }

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
repo-1 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-1.github.com/equinor/repo-1.git" }
repo-2 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-2.github.com/equinor/repo-2.git" }

[tool.poetry.extras]
cicd_modules = ["repo-1", "repo-2"]
```

So that I could run `poetry install` locally and it would use the dev dependencies and `poetry install --no-dev --extras cicd_modules` in the CI/CD pipeline to use the aliased paths. Sadly, this gives me a `CalledProcessError` as it seems like poetry tries to install the optional package despite the optional flag set to true.

What am I doing wrong here, am I using the optional flag incorrectly somehow? Is there a better way to solve this? **In summary I just want to be able to install multiple private repositories as packages using poetry and Github deploy keys in a CI/CD pipeline without breaking local install behaviour**, if it's in this way or another better way, I don't really have a strong opinion on.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue? I ran into it myself when using Github Actions. The ssh-agent action has support for Deploy Keys, but it doesn't work with Poetry - https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent#support-for-github-deploy-keys

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you are inventing new hosts (e.g., repo-1.github.com) but those hostnames don't actually exist, and you are not mapping them to the correct existing hostname (github.com).

Your .ssh/config should look like:

```
Host repo-1.github.com
 Hostname github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo-1-deploy-key
Host repo-2.github.com
 Hostname github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo-2-deploy-keyHost repo-0
```

Then, you can use repo-1.github.com and repo-2.github.com as if they were real hosts, and they will be routed to github.com:

```
...
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
repo-1 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-1.github.com/equinor/repo-1.git" }
repo-2 = { git = "ssh://git@repo-2.github.com/equinor/repo-2.git" }
...
```

Comment: Are you forced to use ssh? If not check if poetry has an equivalent to: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/private-python-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in the CI/CD pipeline a subtly different configuration, consider using a shell script to modify the text of the `pyproject.toml` file. In this case I might use a `sed` one-liner to replace `ssh://git@repo-1.github.com` with `https://PRIVATE_TOKEN:PASSWORD@github.com`.

```bash
sed -i "s/ssh://git@repo-1.github.com/https://$CI_CD_USER:$CI_CD_TOKEN@github.com/g" pyproject.toml
```

And add the appropriate environment variable values for `CI_CD_USER` and `CI_CD_TOKEN` to your configuration.